# Unfinished degree on CV

Tags: resume

I am currently studying mechanical engineering in Croatia, and I have worked 5 years as a software developer. I am moving to another country where I want to work as a software developer. I have one exam left before my degree, which i intend to pass during a future vacation.

Most other questions  i have found about unfinished degrees are about degrees that the person has no intention of finishing.

Is an unfinished degree worth mentioning on a CV? And if so, what is the best way to describe it?

Comment: you might also try https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: well, it is kinda middle ground between academia and workplace

Comment: what country are you moving to?

Comment: Im moving to Ireland.

Comment: XXX University - Graduating in XYZ 2019 (1 unit remaining).  Simple as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same thing all almost-graduates go through when they start applying before finishing their degree.  Put it in, especially if this was a full-time course as that would help explain any gap in your work history.

Be clear that it is currently incomplete, with the expected completion date, and mention you are one exam away. If you can, include your current grade average or equivalent scoring. Also, highlight any specific modules you did really well at, especially if they are relevant to positions you are applying to.

In the end, it is more likely you will be hired for your 5 years experience, but the degree may put you ahead of someone else who has a similar work history.